# Am I using the on_guild_leave function correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

So I looked at many sources saying that `on_guild_leave` is how it is used, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild): # noqa
    try:
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{len(client.guilds)} Servers | !help"))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@client.event
async def on_guild_leave(guild): # noqa
    try:
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{len(client.guilds)} Servers | !help"))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Can anyone seem to help?

`on_guild_join` works, but `on_guild_leave` doesn't.

Comment: any error raised?

Comment: @hardlander nope, no errors, I even had it for Exception to print the Exception, but it never put one, but never worked for `on_guild_leave`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_guild_leave` doesn't exist, use `on_guild_remove` instead. [Docs for on_guild_remove](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_remove)

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't think about that!